# How I can resolve this error message in react? Cannot read property 'details' of null

Tags: reactjs, components

Hello Stackoverflow community!

I'am practicing with react. I am building a very simple shopping cart system. With the app you can select from products. It adds to the shoppingcart. I'm got this error message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'details' of null.

I'am attaching my code.

App.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Shop from "./Shop";
import Cart from "./Cart"

const ShoppingItems = [{
    id: 1,
    
    details: {
        type: "cloth",
        name: "Blue jacket",
        price: 15000
    }
},
{
    id: 2,
    
    details: {
        type: "cloth",
        name: "Trousers",
        price: 9990
    }
},
{
    id: 3,
    
    details: {
        type: "cloth",
        name: "T-shirt",
        price: 5000
    }
}
];

const App = () => {

    const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {console.log(selectedItem)}, [selectedItem]);

    return(
        <div className="ui container">
            <Shop Shopitems={ShoppingItems} setSelectedItem={setSelectedItem}/>
            <Cart selectedItem={selectedItem}/>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Shop.js

```
import React from "react";

const Shop = ({Shopitems, setSelectedItem}) => {

  const AddItem = (id) => {

    const selectedItem = Shopitems.find( item => item.id === id);

    if(selectedItem)
    {
      setSelectedItem(selectedItem);
    }

    return;
  };

  const renderedItems = Shopitems.map((shopitem) => {
    return(

      <div key={shopitem.id} className="card">
        <div className="content">
          <div className="header">{shopitem.details.name}</div>
          <div className="description">
            {shopitem.details.price + " Ft"}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div onClick={() => AddItem(shopitem.id)} className="ui bottom attached button">
          <i className="cart icon"></i>
          Add to cart
        </div>
      </div>
    );

  });
  return (
    <div className="ui cards">{renderedItems}</div>
    
  );
};

export default Shop;
```

Cart.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

const Cart = ({selectedItem}) => {

    const [shoppingCart, setShoppingCart] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {

        //Adding to the shopping cart when an element selected
        setShoppingCart([...shoppingCart, selectedItem]);

    }, [selectedItem]);

    const renderedItems = shoppingCart.map((item) => {
        return(
            <ul>
                <li key={item.id}>
                    <div className="item">
                        {item.details.name}
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        );
    });

    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
            {renderedItems}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Cart;
```

Comment: `{selectedItem && <Cart selectedItem={selectedItem}/>}` - just don't render Cart when nothing is yet selected

Answer (score 0):

It may not be a value for the first time. To solve this problem, you can bet where you have this error:for example:

```
const renderedItems =   Shopitems?Shopitems.map((shopitem) => {
    return(

      <div key={shopitem.id} className="card">
        <div className="content">
          <div className="header">{shopitem.details.name}</div>
          <div className="description">
            {shopitem.details.price + " Ft"}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div onClick={() => AddItem(shopitem.id)} className="ui bottom attached button">
          <i className="cart icon"></i>
          Add to cart
        </div>
      </div>
    );

  }) :[] ;
  return (
    <div className="ui cards">{renderedItems}</div>
    
  );
};

export default Shop;
```

'

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify that selectItem is not null because you cannot use .map on null, it needs to be an array ([]).

change you code to

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Records from './Records';

import Shop from "./Shop";
import Cart from "./Cart"

const ShoppingItems = [{
    id: 1,
    
    details: {
        type: "cloth",
        name: "Blue jacket",
        price: 15000
    }
},
{
    id: 2,
    
    details: {
        type: "cloth",
        name: "Trousers",
        price: 9990
    }
},
{
    id: 3,
    
    details: {
        type: "cloth",
        name: "T-shirt",
        price: 5000
    }
}
];

const App = () => {

    const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {console.log(selectedItem)}, [selectedItem]);

    return(
        <div className="ui container">
          {selectedItem !== null ? <><Shop Shopitems={ShoppingItems} setSelectedItem={setSelectedItem}/>     <Cart selectedItem={selectedItem}/> </>: <></>}
        </div>
    );
};


export default App;
```

This wil render without error but it is blanc page because you pass 'null' as value.